# How do I change the background color of an iron-icon in Polymer?

Tags: html, css, polymer, background-color

I want to change the search iron-icon's background-color to blue. I tried adding a style attribute and setting the background-color: blue but that didn't work. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
<iron-icon icon="icons:search" on-click="doSomething" hidden$="{{disabled}}"></iron-icon>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<iron-icon icon="icons:search" on-click="doSimpleSearch" hidden$="{{disabled}}" class="searchIcon"></iron-icon>

.searchIcon {
            fill: #ffffff;
            *background-color: #3BC2E6;*
            height: 38px;
            width: 60px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

You just need to update the `fill` in css. The default value is `currentColor` which will match your *text* color.

```
<iron-icon icon="icons:search" on-click="doSomething" hidden$="{{disabled}}" 
    style="fill:blue">
</iron-icon>
```

Comment: That changes the actually picture but that did lead me to the right path. Which is as easy as just giving it a style=background-color: blue;

Comment: you're right. I had it right in the title but wrong in the description. I edited it.

Comment: And you said in your own question that you have tried background-color n it doesn't work... Now you are telling me the correct answer is setting the background-color??

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a containing `<div>` and call it like this?

```
.your-div [class*=" icon-"]{
   background-color: red;
}
```

I remember reading somewhere that you have to be really specific when styling them since they are SVG and not Base64 data.

///////////////////// Option 2 /////////////////////

Have you tried simply calling to `iron-icon`? (This one is working for me fine)

```
iron-icon {
    background-color: red;
}
```

///////////////////// Option 3 /////////////////////

My HTML

```
<span class="container vertical center layout flex-1">
<iron-icon class="x-scope iron-icon-0"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="style-scope iron-icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="style-scope iron-icon"><path d="M12 2c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2s-.9 2-2 2-2-.9-2-2 .9-2 2-2zm9 7h-6v13h-2v-6h-2v6H9V9H3V7h18v2z" class="style-scope iron-icon"></path></g></svg>
  </iron-icon>
  <div>icons:accessibility</div>
  </span>
```

My CSS

```
iron-icon:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @user3225968 Updated answer with 2 more possible solutions.